# How to continue a transaction when OPENJSON throws an error?

Tags: sql, transactions, xact-abort

I'm getting a conversion error when updating a table from OPENJSON.  I'm not interesting in solving the conversion error as I'm testing the error handler for when the JSON has bad data.  The transaction is getting aborted (XACT_STATE() = -1).

Is there some way to configure SQL not to abort the transaction?

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- more code
...

-- Update first table from JSON
UPDATE t
SET [field] = [value]
FROM dbo.table t
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON(t.payload, '$')
WITH ([field] [type], ...)

-- Update second table from JSON
UPDATE t
SET [field] = [value]
FROM dbo.table t
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON(t.payload, '$')
WITH ([field] [type], ...)

-- more code
...

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- Handle error
-- Rollback and start a new transaction if necessary.
END CATCH

COMMIT TRANSACTION

Comment: The transaction contains only a single statement. If that statement errors it will be rolled back (regardless of the fact that you’ve wrapped it in a transaction). What are you expecting to happen if it errors? Even if the transaction is not aborted, nothing is going to have happened to your data

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: You haven’t really answered my question. In any case, the point of using transactions is to be able to rollback on failure; if you don’t want that to happen why are you using a transaction?

Comment: I took a step back and thought about what I was trying to do.  I do need the transaction to be rolled back.  I restructured my code and I'm now getting the results I need.  Thanks for your comments.